# Image added through RestResource is not fully uploaded

Tags: apex, rest-api, rest, apexrest

I used [this answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/36868/12408) to make apex rest resource. It works perfectly for small images, but when I want to upload a bit larger image, the bottom part just gets cut.

I was trying to upload [this picture](http://vignette4.wikia.nocookie.net/batman/images/c/c2/Arkham_Batman.png), so I encoded it to base64 on [this site](http://www.base64-image.de/) and then used that Base64 string in my request.

Request went well and the image was attached, but when I preview it, I only see the top part of the image:

[image]

And when I look at the attachment details I see that this image is only 215Kb:

[image]

When I look at the same image on my machine it says that it is 1.1Mb:

[image]

So the question is:
What can be the reason of such behaviour?

Comment: is it happening with all images?

Comment: try uploading multiple images of different sizes.

Comment: @AtulRajguru9 yes, I tried some other images and some of them also get cut. I didn't check their size however

Comment: Try with different image. If happening the same then you will have to post the snippet which does the encoding, sending and attaching.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you already identified, some part of your data is lost somewhere.

I assume the Base64 encoded string gets cut somewhere because it doesn't fit in a window, or field or editor or whatever, and then when you try to upload it, it only uploads a part (the first part) of the image.  Due to the JPG format, it is still able to render the bytes that it *did* receive, i.e. the first part of the image.

So the 'missing bottom part' really is 'the missing last part' of the image and the cause probably is the uploaded Base64 string.

Comment: Hi Willem, thanks for you answer, it did push me in the right direction. I didn't know about the JPG format possibility of showing only the first part, so I thought that it's some undocumented limitation of Salesforce. However, it appears that the encoder I was using only gave me ~215kb, so the problem was with this Base64 string. When I used another encoder I could successfully upload images of +-2mb.